# I need help stacking multiple columns, and creating new columns conditional on their original location

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am looking to take a dataset of test scores and expand it so that I have a table with TestName (ELA, Math, Science), TestDate (ELA = 5/1, Math = 6/1, Sci = 7/1), and Score (W, P, NI, or A)

This is the original table:

```
TestID  ELA Math    Science
1408905 W   W   NI
1020285 NI  P   W
1681155 NI  NI  NI
1987801 P   P   P
1351732 P   NI  NI
1259640 W   W   NI
1833359 NI  NI  P
1624948 P   P   NI
1761110 NI  P   P
1336566 NI  NI  W
1866389 NI  NI  W
1491765 P   A   P
1889694 NI  NI  P
1241930 NI  NI  A
1747558 P   A   W
1023064 P   P   NI
1005327 P   P   P
1586347 A   P   P
```

I've tried

```
conditions = [
    (df['ELA'] != '[]'),
    (df['Math'] != '[]'),
    (df['Science'] != '[]'),
]

values = ['April 1', 'May 1', 'June 1']

df['TestDate'] = np.select(conditions, values)

display(df)
```

But this is the output

```
TestID  ELA Math    Science TestDate
1408905 W   W   NI  April 1
1020285 NI  P   W   April 1
1681155 NI  NI  NI  April 1
1987801 P   P   P   April 1
1351732 P   NI  NI  April 1
1259640 W   W   NI  April 1
1833359 NI  NI  P   April 1
1624948 P   P   NI  April 1
1761110 NI  P   P   April 1
1336566 NI  NI  W   April 1
1866389 NI  NI  W   April 1
1491765 P   A   P   April 1
1889694 NI  NI  P   April 1
1241930 NI  NI  A   April 1
1747558 P   A   W   April 1
1023064 P   P   NI  April 1
1005327 P   P   P   April 1
1586347 A   P   P   April 1
```

Ultimately I'd like everything to be stacked with the TestDate and TestName being conditional on the column they came from and only one column of scores. I'm still very new to this so any help is appreciated!

Expected output should look like this:

```
TestID  TestName TestDate Score
1408905 ELA      April 1   W
1408905 Math     May 1     W
1408905 Science  June 1    NI
1020285 ELA      April 1   NI
1020285 Math     May 1     P
1020285 Science  June 1    W
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are you planning to keep your `testID` column? If possible, please also include your expected output. Thanks

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew Yes the testID column is going to stay - let me edit to show the expected output

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can use `df.melt` to stack your dataframe based on a column

```
ddf = df.melt(id_vars=['TestID'],var_name='Test Name',value_name='Score')
```

Next, you will use a dictionary and a list comprehension to add the column of the test date.

```
values = {'ELA': 'April 1', 'Math': 'May 1', 'Science': 'June 1'}

ddf["Test Date"] = [values[j] for i in ddf["Test Name"] for j in values if j==i]
```

Until then, you will get a sorted dataframe of your data. So, you will need to sort it based on your TestID.

```
ddf.sort_values(by="TestID", inplace=True)
```